# How to find a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ having certain properties

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, cantor-set

Let $n\ge 2$ and let $C$ be a Cantor space in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. That is, $C$ is homeomorphic to the [Cantor ternary set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).

Let $x$ and $y$ be two points in $\mathbb{R}^{n}-C$, and let $L_{xy}$ be the straight line segment joining them. For a fixed $\varepsilon>0$ we would like to to find a homeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that

1. $\phi(x)=x$ and $\phi(y)=y$.
2. Outside an $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $L_{xy}$, $\phi$ is the identity, and $|\phi(z)-z|<\varepsilon$.
3. $\phi(L_{xy})\cap C=\emptyset$.

> How do we construct/show existence of such a homeomorphism $\phi?$

Comment: The "fixed outside a neighborhood" part will following by the stable homeomorphism theorem; if you can get a(n orientation-preserving) homeomorphism sufficiently close to the identity, it will be isotopic to one with compact support outside a neighborhood of your arc.  I'm more worried about if your arc passes through a point of a Cantor Set which isn't movable.  Your question is about the movability of Cantor Sets, i.e. Cantor Sets $C$ such that there are ambient isotopies which instantaneously move $C$ off itself.  There are immovable Cantor Sets in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: In the plane, all Cantor Sets are isotopic, so after suitable isotopy (which you can take to be the identity on small neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$, but it's very technical proving the isotopy versions of Schoenflies/Stable Homeomorphism Thm etc.) you can assume it's the standard ternary Cantor Set.  In which case it's clearly true.

Comment: @JohnSamples: I can answer the question as stated but I do not see how it relates to all the other issues you are raising (movability of Cantor sets, etc.).

Comment: Well if the arc passed through an immovable Cantor set then you wouldn't be able to move it off the Cantor set within $\epsilon$ time for very small $\epsilon$, I think.  That was the only type of obstruction I could think of.  If you can just answer their version without dealing with such terms then that's fine ofc!

Comment: Oh, I only just noticed that their path $L$ is a straight line . . . I'm curious about when $L$ is just any path, as well.  But I'll still award the bounty just for their version.

Comment: Yes, having a straight line makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will first give a proof in the case $n\ge 3$ and then explain how to modify it to include the case $n=2$.

Without loss of generality (after applying a rotation and rescaling), the segment $L=L_{xy}$ is contained in the $x_n$-axis, and also $x=0$ and $y=(0,...,0,1)$.

Take $m\in {\mathbb N}$ sufficiently large (see below) and for $i=0,...,m-1$ consider congruent cubes $Q_i$ in $R^n$ given by the inequalities
$$
- \frac{1}{2m} \le x_k\le \frac{1}{2m}, k=1,...,n-1, \frac{i}{m}\le x_n\le \frac{i+1}{m}.  
$$
These closed cubes cover the unit interval $L$; $x$ belongs to the bottom of the first cube and $y$ belongs to the top of the last cube.  Set
$$
Q:= Q_0\cup...\cup Q_{m-1}, U:= {\mathbb R}^n \setminus Q.
$$
The number $m$ is chosen so that the diameter of each cube is $\le \epsilon$. In each cube $Q_i$ inscribe the sphere $\Sigma_i$ of diameter $1/m$. (The center of the sphere lies on the segment $L$.) It suffices to consider the case when the intersection points of these spheres with $L$ are all disjoint with the Cantor set $C$.
(This is achieved by moving the points $x, y$ a bit along the $x_n$-axis.) These intersection points are
$$
p_i=(0,...,0, \frac{i}{m}), i=0,...,m. 
$$
I will use the notation $L_i$ for the segments $p_i p_{i+1}$.
Since the dimension of each sphere is $\ge 2$ (this is where I use the assumption $n\ge 3$), the intersection $C\cap \Sigma_i$
does not separate this sphere. Therefore, for each $i$ there exists a smooth *simple* path $c_i$ in $\Sigma_i$ which is disjoint from
$C\cup \partial Q_i$ except for the end-points  $p_i$, $p_{i+1}$ which, of course, lie on $\partial Q_i$.

Since $c_i$ lies on the sphere $\Sigma_i$, it is "unknotted" in the cube $Q_i$ (where the unknotedness is understood relative the end-points of $c_i$ which are supposed to be fixed by the unknotting isotopy).

**Remark.** Of course, the unknotedness is only an issue in the case $n=3$, in higher dimensions it is automatic.

Hence, for each $i$ there exists a self-homeomorphism $f_i: Q_i\to Q_i$ which equals the identity on the boundary of the cube and takes $L_i$ to $c_i$. Extend these homeomorphisms by the identity to the $U$. The result
is a homeomorphism $f: {\mathbb R}^n\to {\mathbb R}^n$.  By the assumption about the diameters of the cubes $Q_i$, the map
$f$ has displacement $\le \epsilon$:
$$
 d(z, f(z))\le \epsilon ~~\forall~z\in {\mathbb R}^n. 
 $$
By the construction, $f$ takes $L$ to the concatenation of the curves
$$
 c=c_0\star c_1\star .... \star c_{m-1},
 $$
which is a curve connecting $x$ to $y$ and disjoint from $C$.

This completes the proof in the case $n\ge 3$. To deal with the case $n=2$, we do not need the circles $\Sigma_i$, but for each $i$ take any smooth simple path $c_i$ in $Q_i$ connecting $p_i$ to $p_{i+1}$ and disjoint from
$C\cup \partial Q_i$ except for the end-points  $p_i$, $p_{i+1}$ which, of course, lie on $\partial Q_i$. In dimension 2 any path in a square is unknotted, hence, we  again get our homeomorphism $f_i: Q_i\to Q_i$, taking $L_i$ to $c_i$ and equal to the identity on $\partial Q_i$. The rest of the proof is the same as for dimensions $n\ge 3$. qed

Comment: Nice, very clean!  I think you will need to make sure none of the points on the spheres touch $C$ as well, but this is easy by just allowing the diameters to be different.  I think you actually don't want them inscribed and touching the cube boundaries, though I guess they only touch in four points so it doesn't matter.  I'll look around a bit and see if it's still true for arbitrary paths in $\mathbb{R}^3$; if I don't find an answer either way I'll post it as a separate question.  I'm also curious about when you can do it as an isotopy relative to $C \setminus P$.

Comment: Having $C$ intersecting spheres is not a problem, just not at the intersection points of the spheres with $L$. Yes, shrinking the spheres a bit is another way to argue, but finitely many points of tangency with the boundaries of cubes is not a problem since the union of these with $C\cap \Sigma_i$ still does not separate $\Sigma_i$.

Comment: Oops, I meant none of the sphere-line intersection points.

Comment: Not clearly relevant, but a really cool paper: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-031-02/S0002-9939-1972-0284992-2/S0002-9939-1972-0284992-2.pdf